# Helm 3.6.1 fails to fetch (Unauthorized) from authenticated repo

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I added a new repo with the command:

`helm repo add <name> <url> --username <user> --password <pass>`

Then, when trying to pull a chart from it with:

`helm pull <repo_name>/<chart_name> --version "$chart_version" --untar`

I am getting 401 Unauthorized.

Helm version is 3.6.1. Locally with version 3.1.2 everything works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a bug with v3.6.1, adding the repo with `--pass-credentials`

To know more refer to this [issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/RTFACT-26063/RTFACT-26063.html) and this [other](https://github.com/helm/helm/security/advisories/GHSA-56hp-xqp3-w2jf)

Edit: version 3.6.3 also works as expected