# Error: Azure Devops HelmDeploy@0 upgrade command

Tags: azure-devops, devops, kubernetes-helm

I am facing error while using HelmDeploy@0 task for helm upgrade with ACR with MS hosted agent. Here is the sample code.

Helm version: 3.6.2

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
          displayName: Login to Azure Container Registry
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: rm-dev-svc-conn
            scriptType: bash
            scriptLocation: inlineScript
            inlineScript: |
              az acr login --name acrazdotest.azurecr.io
 - task: HelmDeploy@0
          inputs:
            command: upgrade
            connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
            chartType: 'Name'
            chartName: 'oci://acrazdotest.azurecr.io/helm/charts/${{ parameters.servicename }}:0.2.0'
            azureSubscriptionEndpointForACR: 'rm-dev-svc-conn'
            azureResourceGroupForACR: rg-acr-azdo-test
            azureContainerRegistry: 'acrazdotest.azurecr.io/helm/charts/${{ parameters.servicename }}'
            kubernetesServiceEndpoint: test-devops-devops-1677149227624
            install: true
            releaseName: '${{ parameters.servicename }}'
            namespace: devops
            arguments: '-f dev-values.yaml --dry-run --debug'
            overridevalues: |
              container.image.tag=206
              imagePullSecrets=acrimgpull
```

Error: with Linux agent:  **failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized**

with windows agent: ##[error]history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release service-api
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
Error: link error: cannot rename C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\helm\repository\service-api:0.2.0-.**tgz049965911** to C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\helm\repository\service-api:0.2.0-.tgz:

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374452/helm-3-6-1-fails-to-fetch-unauthorized-from-authenticated-repo